# How to use MapboxGeocoder with no map in React

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, react-ref

I'm trying to use Mapbox Geocoder without map in React (see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-no-map/ ). I can successfully create a refs but once I use it as an argument in `.addTo()` function, I get this error message although the refs is an `[object HTMLDivElement]`:

```
Error: addTo Container must be a mapbox-gl-js map or a html element reference
```

The code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-hill-xvh12?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#addto you must pass a string selector like `#id` or `.class` to addTo, not a reference to the actual element.

Comment: String refs are deprecated in React (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) so is there another way around?